# ViewStub with custom View attributes for target layout

Tags: android, custom-attributes, viewstub

Is it possible to pass custom attributes through a ViewStub to the target layout's root element? Like so:

```
<ViewStub
        android:layout="@layout/custom_view"
        app:customAttr="12345"
        />
```

Where custom_view.xml is:

```
<blah.CustomView ...>
    ...
</blah.CustomView>
```

When I try to do that, CustomView.java does not get "app:customAttr" in the AttributeSet.

When I use CustomView directly, without ViewStub

```
<blah.Custom app:customAttr="12345"/>
```

The attribute gets into the AttributeSet ok.

But it's not lazy anymore.

Any solutions?

Thank you,
Yuri.

Answer (score 2):

Like `<include>` the only attributes that ViewStub lets you override are the layout attributes and which id the child view will have after inflation.